# convert string to array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this string: `test1__test2__test3__test4__test5__test6=value`

There could be any number of test-keys.

I want to write a function that can turn the string above into an array

```
$data[test1][test2][test3][test4][test5][test6] = "value";
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Seems a bit complicated, why do you need to do this for?

Comment: Is it always going to be 6 items or more/less?

Comment: @Salman: "There could be any number of test-keys." -- I guess 6 is an arbitrary example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = array();

// Supposing you have multiple strings to analyse...
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    // Split at '=' to separate key and value parts.
    list($key, $value) = explode("=", $string);

    // Current storage destination is the root data array.
    $current =& $data;

    // Split by '__' and remove the last part
    $parts = explode("__", $key);
    $last_part = array_pop($parts);

    // Create nested arrays for each remaining part.
    foreach ($parts as $part)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($part, $current) || !is_array($current[$part])) {
            $current[$part] = array();
        }
        $current =& $current[$part];
    }

    // $current is now the deepest array ($data['test1']['test2'][...]['test5']).
    // Assign the value to his array, using the last part ('test6') as key.
    $current[$last_part] = $value;
}
```

Comment: thanks for that. I needed to analyze a lot of strings and then compile one big array.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible:

```
list($keys, $value) = explode('=', $str);
$keys = explode('__', $keys);

$t = &$data;
$last = array_pop($keys);

foreach($keys as $key) {
    if(!isset($t[$key]) || !is_array($t[$key])) {
        // will override non array values if present
        $t[$key] = array();
    }
    $t = &$t[$key];
}

$t[$last] = $value;
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/UT5PtGbp)

**Reference**: [`list`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php), [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [`=&`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php#language.operators.assignment.reference), [`is_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php), [`array_pop`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

Comment: @Ferdinand: Thanks! That happens when you code too fast :D ;)

Comment: Furthermore, `is_array($data[$key])` will issue warnings (or even errors?) if `$key` is not in `$data`. Did you mean `isset()`? ;)

Comment: @Ferdinand: You are right, it gives a notice. But no, I wanted to use `is_array`. Just have to add `isset`. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Thank you for the references.

Comment: if you look at the output of the demo more closely you'll notice `test6` appears twice.

Answer (score 3):

```
function special_explode($string) {
  $keyval = explode('=', $string);
  $keys = explode('__', $keyval[0]);
  $result = array();

  //$last is a reference to the latest inserted element                         
  $last =& $result;
  foreach($keys as $k) {
    $last[$k] = array();
    //Move $last                                                                
    $last =& $last[$k];
  }

  //Set value                                                                   
  $last = $keyval[1];
  return $result;
}

//Test code:
$string = 'test1__test2__test3__test4__test5__test6=value';
print_r(special_explode($string));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = ...;
eval( str_replace('__', '][', 
preg_replace('/^(.*)=(.*)$/', '\$data[$1]=\'$2\';', $str)) );
```

easier way, assuming the `$str` is trustable data

Comment: You should at least add quotes to the keys.  Otherwise you will get warnings that you use undefined constants, and, if one of the keys happens to be a constant name, you will get into trouble.  Maybe you should also emphasize the **trustable** aspect...

Comment: Agree with Ferinand. But otherwise nice solution. It's the first piece of code with `eval` I see, which I would've accepted in my own project 8) .

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is...

```
$string = "test1__test2__test3__test4__test5__test6=value";
$values = explode('=',$string);
$indexes = explode('__',$values[0]);
$data[$indexes[0]][$indexes[1]][$indexes[2]][$indexes[3]][$indexes[4]][$indexes[5]] = $values[1];
```

Comment: `explode()` can't handle regular expressions, so `explode('_+')` won't split on `__`.